# Coercivity of a(u,v) on L2

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We want to prove coercivity of the bilinear form:

$$a(u,v) = (\nabla u, \nabla v),$$
for $u,v \in H_0^1.$

Why is showing that $a(u,v)$ is coercive on $L_2$ (e.g. $||u||^2_{L_2} \leq |a(u,u)|$
) not enough as a part of proving the uniqueness of solution $u$ by using the Lax-Milgram lemma? Why does the result have to be stated in the $H_1$ norm: $||u||^2_{H_1} \leq |a(u,u)|$?

Comment: hint: use poincare's inequality

Comment: @fGDu94 I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: The reason is the fact that your vector space is $V = H^1_0$. Technically, it suffices to show $\|u|_2 \le \|\nabla u\|_2$ since $\|\nabla u\|_2 \le \|\nabla u\|_2$